# Problems with certain Unicode characters

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, unicode, microsoft-word-2016, chinese

I am using word, and I needed to insert the name of the Chinese Nüshu script in Nüshu (), there wasn't a font that supported it, so I downloaded every font I could find that supported it. Noto Sans Nushu, Noto Traditional Nushu, and a rip of the font on the unicode character sheet (cannot link due to less than 10 reputation). I tried using it in word and it didn't work, the font kept trying to change to Yu Gothic (my default Asian text font). When those fonts didn't work, I created my own in FontForge, but word did the same thing, so **I'm sure it's Word's fault**.

The font appears correctly in the [fonts screen preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35I9w.png) but not [on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxulw.png). It also works fine in [WordPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7TSo.png) and when changing the font in [Notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMpBN.png). I tried using Microsoft forums, however they kept insisting it's a problem with the fonts I'm using; however I'm like 99% sure Word just doesn't realise that that character is in the font. **It's probably because word takes the characters to be Asian, but not the font, so it sets it to a default Asian font**. It may be because the Unicode number is so large, it doesn't know what to do with it? (I doubt this is the problem because fonts [seem to work fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb1m8.png) for the unicode block following Nüshu: Duployan)

**Finally, using the styles tab to force the Asian text font to be a Nüshu font [makes the characters invisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OogTV.png)**.

**Does anyone have a solution to this problem?** Is there a way to set a font to be Asian? Is there any way to force text to use a font even if Word thinks that the font doesn't support the characters? (though I assume the same thing would happen as using the styles tab.)

I have tried creating a new document, updating Word, and reinstalling Office.

[Nüshu code chart](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1B170.pdf)
[Script info](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/scripts/Nshu)

Word version 2022 (Build 14931.20724 Click-to-Run)

Comment: you know this image you included here https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMpBN.png   for showing the characters in notepad. Can you open charmap.exe and choose your font, and find the characters in that and state what the unicode code for it is? or show a screenshot of it in character map so we can see how we can produce that character

Comment: Have you insured that the text is set to the right font?

Comment: @barlop [Here](https://imgur.com/4HfCIB8) it's completely empty. I assume because charmap.exe only supports 16 bit Unicode characters and nothing more... the input box only allows four characters. I tried inserting 1B2F1 (for the character ) and it wouldn't let me enter the last digit. Interestingly the word symbol insert tool [does show the characters](https://imgur.com/nI2kT9L).

Comment: **Update**: I have injected the characters into a different Asian font (Noto Sans Traditional Chinese) and it works, so now I'm certain that the issue is that word recognises Nüshu as Asian text, but does not recognise the font as an Asian font and refuses to let it be set to that. Although it works, it is more of a temporary bodge than a solution. If the problem is the font and there's some value that word looks at to determine if a font is Asian or not then please let me know.

Comment: I know Win XP had categories for "complex scripts right to left languages", and "east asian languages".. (and they are maybe still treated differently now in Win10), I haven't really tested out the "east asian languages" ..  Another route you could try for answers is a chinese tech forum, What you can do is use a program called Babelmap https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html  which is a more powerful form of character map.  And  what characters are supported by a font. And it has a search to show you what fonts support a particular character

Comment: @barlop That's not the problem. I know the font supports those characters because it renders properly in every software except Word and Outlook, which happen to be the two that support rich MS text.